# question relating to weak minimum principle.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This question was from my class test. I would like to know how to solve it.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: How about you start and we'll chime in?

Answer (score 1):

Try $\varphi=u^-$; if you are unfamiliar with this notation, it means $\max(-u,0)$.